# Ionic Testing in Chrome with IonicStorage

Tags: cordova, google-chrome, ionic3, ionic-storage

I'm building an Ionic 3 App using the new IonicStorage.  I'm setting a bearerToken as so...

```
//store the BearerToken
setToken(token){
this.storage.set('bearertoken',token);
}
```

All works well and everything comes back very nicely...until....I make a change to the code and live reload happens.  It should retrieve the token as the platform is ready as such:

```
getToken(){
this.storage.get('bearertoken')
.then((val) => {
  return val;
})
}
```

But the value is always empty as if it totally got wiped.  Is this the way it should be when testing in the browser?

Comment: I think the way you return value is causing you this issue. Basically get/then is returning a promise so not sure how you handle this. Try assigning the value to a variable: this.myToken = val within your callback function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do it via a var. Not sure what you are trying to achieve by returning a value in in the callback.

```js
// declare a var before constructor in your component:
token: string = "";

getToken(){
  this.storage.get('bearertoken')
    .then((val) => {
      this.token = val;
    })
}
```

Comment: Ah...that was it.  Kinda silly I didn't catch that, but sometimes an extra pair of eyes is exactly what is needed.  Thanks so much!!